# blank screen magento configuration after unstalling module

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Apologies if this is a duplicate question but I have searched and I cant find anything similar.

OK, I am running Magento 1.9.1.0

I recently uninstalled raveinfosys order exporter and now I cant access anything under the system menu besides magento connect.  I cleared the cache manually but still no luck. Compiler is not enabled.

Attached is what I see [IMG]http://i62.tinypic.com/2rfpoua.jpg[/IMG]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it guys!

restarted the memcached service on the server.